# Подключение к бд Oracle на VS 2015 MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oracle

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться как осуществить правильную связь с БД Oracle в MVC 4 в VS 2015. 
В MVC только учусь, в консольном приложении писал следующие: 
Подключал Oracle.DataAccess.dll затем:

```
 try
    {
        string oradb = "Data Source = 192.168.0.2/orcl; User id = user; password = 1234";

        OracleConnection connect = new OracleConnection(oradb);

        connect.Open();

        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();

        cmd.Connection = connect;

        cmd.CommandText = "Select * from users";

        OracleDataReader dateReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        dateReader.Read();

        Console.WriteLine("Test{0}", dateReader.GetChar(1));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Ошибка{0}", ex);
    }
```

Помогите, если можно с примером, большое спасибо

Comment: делайте так же (если этот способ работает). В чём проблема-то?

Comment: @DreamChild Да нет больших проблем, думал что-то изменилось с тех пор.

Comment: и это выглядит как-то иначе

Comment: @DreamChild Хотел бы проконсультироваться в правильности создания соединения, как лучше это сделать ? создать отдельно класс, а затем контроллер унаследовать от этого класса ? как правильно делать запросы к базе ? спасибо